# Apache2 default page shows without http://, https:// or www. prefix

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, redirect, apache2

I am running a django webapp on a ubuntu 19.04 server with apache2. I have installed a SSL certificate with certbot and I'm unable to direct traffic from domainname.com to https://www.domainname.com. Whenever I browse to domainname.com, the apache default page is shown. If I browse to www.domainname.com, the website shows as expected. https://domainname.com works fine however.

I haven't found a solution that works for me, what's troubling me is that I have a ssl certificate and two conf files.

In running certbot, an extra config file was created, so I now have domainname.conf and domainname-le-ssl.conf. Now in my domainname.conf I have added a rewrite so that all traffic to my 80 port gets redirected to https: :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName www.domainname.com
        ServerAdmin *******
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domainname.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

My domainname-le-ssl.conf was generated automatically by certbot and does not have any rewrites. Now I've tried some rewrites but none seem to pick up that all traffic should go over https and to www.domainname.com. Is this something I should fix in this file or at the service where I registered my domain?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by replacing my rewrite logic to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```